# Page not appearing in site pages library

Tags: deployment, feature, module

I want to deploy a page to the sitepages library.  When i deploy this code it does not appear.

However when i go to the url manually e.g. contoso.com/SitePages/mytestpage.html, i get the 'save as' options with the page, which means it has been deployed fine, but i cant figure out why it does not appear in the list.

Below is my code.

Does this have anything to do with the fact that it is a html page and not a aspx page?

Comment: I think your code was not posted due to some error. Can you try posting it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I can think of is to check whether you have set the `Type` attribute of your file as `GhostableInLibrary`. This should make it appear in the list.

Eg:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="Pages" Url="SitePages">
     <File Path="Pages\mytestpage.html" Url="mytestpage.html" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
  </Module>
</Elements>
```